# Connect to Bluetooth Device via Java Code

Tags: java, bluetooth, bluecove

I want to connect to another bluetooth device through my laptop's bluetooth.

I'm using bluecove library for my reference. My environment is as below
Machine: Ubuntu 12.4, Quad Core, 8GB Ram.
Java: 1.8
Blueove: bluecove-2.1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar, bluecove-gpl-2.1.0.jar

I have written below code to connect to the local bluetooth device.

```
   LocalDevice localDevice = LocalDevice.getLocalDevice();
        DiscoveryAgent agent = localDevice.getDiscoveryAgent();
        agent.startInquiry(DiscoveryAgent.GIAC, listener);
```

But Im getting below error when I execute this code.

```
Native Library bluecove not available
javax.bluetooth.BluetoothStateException: BlueCove library bluecove not available;
resource not found libbluecove.so
load [bluecove] no bluecove in java.library.path
    at com.intel.bluetooth.BlueCoveImpl.loadNativeLibraries(BlueCoveImpl.java:396)
    at com.intel.bluetooth.BlueCoveImpl.detectStack(BlueCoveImpl.java:450)
    at com.intel.bluetooth.BlueCoveImpl.access$500(BlueCoveImpl.java:69)
    at com.intel.bluetooth.BlueCoveImpl$1.run(BlueCoveImpl.java:1044)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.intel.bluetooth.BlueCoveImpl.detectStackPrivileged(BlueCoveImpl.java:1042)
    at com.intel.bluetooth.BlueCoveImpl.getBluetoothStack(BlueCoveImpl.java:1035)
    at javax.bluetooth.LocalDevice.getLocalDeviceInstance(LocalDevice.java:75)
    at javax.bluetooth.LocalDevice.getLocalDevice(LocalDevice.java:95)
    at bt.MyDiscoveryListener.main(MyDiscoveryListener.java:36)
```

Kindly help me out to get rid this of error. I have also tried with building native library but it didn't help.

I appreciate all your answers.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to start your JRE like this:
`java.exe -Djava.library.path=your_path_to_libbluecove.so ...other options...`
This should at least solve the problem with 'resource not found'.

Comment: Thanks Chris. Actually I have tried with command java -Djava.library.path=libbluecove.so -cp bluecove-2.1.0.jar:bluecove-gpl-2.1.0.jar:bluetooth.jar bt.MyDiscoveryListener but still it gives same error.

Comment: Are the .so and the JRE both 32-bit or both 64-bit?

Comment: The last thing i could suggest is to type the full path to the libbluecove.so in the java.library.path. 'Resource not found' seems to be a really clear message...

Answer (score 0):

If you use this never released snapshot of BlueCove:
[BlueCove 2.1.2](http://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-attachments/bluecove/issue-134/comment-21/bluecove-2.1.2.jar)

It adds support for 64 bit